# Error with ios simulator on specifc project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have problem with the simulator, I have project which was running perfectly yesterday on the simulator (i didn't change any code) , today i am trying to run the project it gives me white blank screen only, I have tried another projects they work expect this project does anybody face this problem before , any help ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on console? You need to provide more information. Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: i did what you said , clean , build , remove the project from the simulator and run it again , no errors in the console , just white screen if i pressed shift+command+H to go home it go to the home screen its like the project is opened but white screen is shown

Comment: Within the simulator, go to the top-menu and select "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings"

Comment: Go to xcode preferences -> Locations ->  Derived data -> click on arrow icon. finder will show the derived data folder. Quit xcode, trash the derived data folder and then empty the trash.

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to tell, but this sounds like an autolayout issue to me.  Please read through the many questions here with the autolayout tag for possible help.